# How to use google Calender API in java gwt application

Tags: java, gwt, google-calendar-api

I am working on some project. I want to use google calender api in my project. I searched google for google calender API but i did not get user friendly information. So could you help me for which jar shall i include in my project to use calender API with java gwt. and any example which helps how to use google Calender API.
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Google API Client Library for Java does not support Google Web Toolkit (GWT), Java mobile (ME), and Java 1.4 (or earlier) and it supports Java 5 or higher, standard (SE) and enterprise (EE), Google App Engine and Android 1.5 or above.

Google uses REST and OAuth2.

Read this for getting OAuth2 authentication token 
[oauth 2.0 gwt access token and google calendar api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557677/oauth-2-0-gwt-access-token-and-google-calendar-api)

Use RequestBuilder and access the calendar api as a rest service

References:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json?csw=1#Request

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your valuable comment how can i access calender api in gwt and what jar shall i download and from where?? i am using java1.7 and gwt 2.6.1

Comment: gwt-servlet.jar will help you in making JsonpRequestBuilder call. Download link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet/2.7.0-rc1

Comment: using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557677/oauth-2-0-gwt-access-token-and-google-calendar-api i did not get could you tell me how can i use calender api example